# Go to a QDataWidgetMapper element after addMapping - Bug?

Tags: qt

I've had some strange problems initializing a QDataWidgetMapper.

If I do it this way it works, but there is no sync between the Widgets:

```
dataMapper->setModel(model);
dataMapper->toFirst();
dataMapper->addMapping(ui.uiName, 0);
```

The documentation doesn't tell me to go to any element (I do it by calling toFirst())

If I try to go to the first element AFTER i map to a Widget it crushes with an index out of range error:

```
dataMapper->setModel(model);
dataMapper->addMapping(ui.uiName, 0);
dataMapper->toFirst();
```

Just if i bypass it like this it works how presumed:

```
dataMapper->setModel(model);
dataMapper->toFirst();
dataMapper->addMapping(ui.uiName, 0);
dataMapper->toFirst();
```

Can someone tell me why this is necessary in my case? Is there maybe an bug in my own Model implementation or is it common to do it this way? But if it is common, why isn't it mentioned in the documentation or any example?

Regards